# Capitalize and add period sign in intials (using Regex Replace)

Tags: c#, regex

I want to add period signs to a initials, and ensure that all letters are capitalized.
However, if period signs are already given, than don't add one.

Wanted results: 
abc   => A.B.C. 
Abc   => A.B.C. 
A.b.c => A.B.C. 
Ab.C  => A.B.C. 
ABC   => A.B.C. 
A.B.C => A.B.C. 
A.B.C.=> A.B.C.

I imagined regex replace would be suitable/optimal for this. So far I could only come up with the following code:

```
Regex.Replace(initials, @"\w{1}", m => m +".").ToUpper();
```

This works only in the scenario's when there are no periods in the string, otherwise, it will just add two periods in a row (i.e. a.b.c => a..b..c..)

If other methods than regex replace are more recommended, I warmly welcome them. I work in c#, but wanted to keep the question general to other languages as well.

Comment: Check out [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/rpa8ou/1) and use it with `.ToUpper()`. Does this fit your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

```
\p{L}\.*
```

pattern, or (c# code):

```
initials = Regex.Replace(
  initials, 
 @"\p{L}\.*", 
  m => $"{m.Value.Trim('.').ToUpper()}.");
```

**pattern explained**:

```
\p{L}  - unicode letter
\.*    - zero or more dots ('.')
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "abc",
    "Abc",
    "A.b.c",
    "Ab.C",
    "ABC",
    "A.B.C",
    "A.B.C.",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,7} => {Regex.Replace(test, @"\p{L}\.*", m => $"{m.Value.Trim('.').ToUpper()}.")}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
    abc => A.B.C.
    Abc => A.B.C.
  A.b.c => A.B.C.
   Ab.C => A.B.C.
    ABC => A.B.C.
  A.B.C => A.B.C.
 A.B.C. => A.B.C.
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about `c#` but pieced together the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main() {
        var txt = "Ab.C";
        var new_txt = Regex.Replace(txt, @"(\w)\.?", @"$1.").ToUpper();
        Console.Write(new_txt);
    }
}
```

The pattern `(\w)\.?` means:

- `(\w)` - A capture group of a word-char.
- `\.?` - Followed by an optional dot.

Mind you, `\w` could capture more in `c#` then just `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w). Meaning you may want to be more specific using a character class.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make use of the [capture collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection?view=net-6.0) using a repeated capture group to repeat n times a character followed by an optional dot.

```
(?:(\w)\.?){3,}
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%5cw%29%5c.%3f%29%7b3%2c%7d&i=A.bc).

For example:

```
string[] strings = {
    "abc",
    "Abc",
    "Ab.C",
    "ABC",
    "A.B.C",
    "A.B.C."
    };

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(
        s,
        @"(?:(\w)\.?){3,}", 
        m => string.Join("", m.Groups[1].Captures.Select(x => x + ".")).ToUpper())
    );
}
```

Output

```
A.B.C.
A.B.C.
A.B.C.
A.B.C.
A.B.C.
A.B.C.
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach without RegEx

```
string result = string.Concat(input.Where(IsLetter).Select(x => char.ToUpper(x) + "."));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/macBWv

Comment: The solution is correct, providing that `input` can contain letters and dots only. If it's not the case and we have say, *dash*, e.g. `j-c.d.` for `Jan-Christian Dreesen` we have to use *regex*